# Is there an extended-life battery for the Sony NEX-6?

Tags: battery, timelapse, sony-nex, battery-grip

I'm really enjoying my Sony NEX-6, especially the time-lapse application. However, I'm often finding that the camera's battery dies before I can create a long time-lapse (say, 4-5 hours). Is there a way to either:
(a) charge the camera while it's taking the time-lapse, or (b) purchase a battery grip for the camera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an AC Adaptor - The [Sony AC-PW20](https://store.sony.com/ac-adaptor-zid27-ACPW20/cat-27-catid-All-Cameras-Alpha-DSLR-Accessories) is the option here.

Alternatively you could buy a third party non-OEM battery that is rated above the OEM battery in capacity. The Sony NP-FW50 is rated at 1080 mAh and you can find [some](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004DOZDKQ) 1500 mAh options out there if you look.

Answer (score 0):

As a warning to anyone thinking of buying a [USB battery pack](http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-usb-battery-pack-travel/), don't -- my NEX goes into USB mode when I plug in a USB cable, even if it's a charge-only cable. Which means that it doesn't let you take photos -- the entire UI is replaced by a "USB" indicator.

I tried changing the USB mode from mass storage to MTP to auto, to no avail.